# Некорректное значение

Tags: php, postgresql

При выполнении запроса на вставку из консоли, всё корректно работает, но при выполнение на сервере, часть символов обрезается либо в нечитабельные символы преобразуется.

> Результат консольный: D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\downloading 
> Результат на сервере: D:SteamLibrarysteamappsdownloadin

Если выполнить `echo` или `var_dump`, там показывается корректное значение.

Смена типов и размеров то же не помогла.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$date_and_time_server = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_base user=testuser password=admin");
if (!$conn)
{
    echo "Произошла ошибка.\n";
    exit;
}

foreach ($data as $item)
{
    $product = array(
        'id_user'     => 1,
        'name_file'   => $item->NameFile,
        'path_file'   => $item->PathFile,
        'date_local'  => $item->DateLocal . " " . $item->TimeLocal,
        'date_server' => $date_and_time_server
    );
    $res = pg_insert($conn, 'shop.products', $product);
    if ($res) {
        echo "Данные успешно внесены \n";
    } else {
        echo "Пользователь прислал неверные данные\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

При таком Insert всё корректно начало вставляться.

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO shop.products (id_user, name_file, path_file, date_local, date_server) VALUES ('$id_user', '$name_process', '$path_process', '$date_local', '$date_and_time_server')";
$res = pg_query($conn, $query);
?>
```